# Mono .NET Error 500

Tags: mono

Greetings,

When I tried to deploy my .net solution in my rented hosting server I got this error...

This is very weird because, no matter if the code is running smooth or not this always happen?

```
Server Error in '/' Application
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPrecompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPrecompiledApplicationType () [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] 

Version information: Mono Version: 2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

Can someone explain me what is happening and how can I solve this

Comment: Is your web application ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC? Do you know which web server your hosting server is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting this http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td23255638